# Nested pair of for loops returns None and does not iterate

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, iteration

I am just starting out using Python for data manipulation, and I am having trouble with a pair of nested for-loops that do not iterate. The goal is to match rows in a csv data file to items in a list, but after performing operations with the data rows for the first item in the list, it stops.

An example of the problem is:

```
with open(infiles[3], 'rU') as inf3:
    firmyeardata3=csv.reader(inf3, dialect='excel')
    for i in firmyearlist:
        firm=firmyeardatadict[i][2]
        for row in firmyeardata3:
            if row[1]==firm:
                print firm
```

Instead of iterating through the entire list, this code give me:

```
firmx
firmx
firmx
firmx
firmx
firmx
None
```

The `None` looks like an obvious problem, but I'm at a loss about where it's coming from and why it's interrupting the loop.

Comment: What does the csv look like?

Comment: It's a list of transactions that was originally in .xlsx format. So the goal is to add up qualities of the transactions for each firm across time. More specifically, it has the other party to the transaction, date, amount, etc.

Comment: How are you getting `firmyeardatadict`?

Comment: I created a dictionary with a list as the default value.
firmyeardatadict=defaultdict(list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read a `csv.reader()` object only once (like any other file, by the way). That means that after the first `for row in firmyeardata3:` loop has finished, there is nothing left to iterate over.

You might want to read the CSV file into a list and then iterate over that repeatedly.